# Accesing variables inside the forEach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

i have little problem in accessing variables from a forEach loop, that loops around an array of objects,  outside the loop.
i already tried declaring variables and assigning them to the ones in the forEach loop but it was unsucsessful because it only returns the first value.

```
let bestPrice;
let injectInstruments;
allInstruments.forEach(function (instrument) {
    
    let price = instrument.price;
    let type = instrument.type;
    let description = instrument.description;
    let picture = instrument.picture;
   
     injectInstruments =instrumentsContainer.innerHTML= `<div  hidden 
    instrumentType='${type}'class="box instrument" price="${price}">
        <img class="instrument-image" src="${picture}" alt="">
       <h6 class="price">${price}</h6>
        <p class="instrument-description">${description}</p>
    </div>`
   bestPrice=price
})
console.log(injectInstruments);
console.log(bestPrice);
```

Comment: what is the error, what are you trying to accomplish? give a little more details. you are able to access injectInstruments but its undefined, so it won't have innerHtml property

Comment: so , i need to access the variables price, type etc outside because they are going to be used in a filter I also need to inject those proprieties into html. the problem is that if i console.log(injectInstruments) inside the loop, it gives me the correct output, but outside the loop, its undefined and the string is not injected into html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue

- `bestPrice` is overwritten every loop.
- `instrumentsContainer.innerHTML` is overwritten every loop.
- You don't need to access `injectInstruments` to insert html because `.innerHTML = ''` changes html.
- `injectInstruments =instrumentsContainer.innerHTML='<div ...>'` has 3 equals `=`, which causes a syntax error.

### Solution

- Use `.insertAdjacentHTML()` instead of `.innerHTML`. The former adds html into a container, the latter overwrites a container's content completely.
- If you want to access only prices, store prices in an array.

```js
// Get the container <div>
const instrumentsContainer = document.querySelector('div');

const allInstruments = [{
    price: 100,
    type: 'something',
    description: 'lorem ipsum',
    picture: './image1.jpg'
  },
  {
    price: 200,
    type: 'something2',
    description: 'lorem ipsum2',
    picture: './image2.jpg'
  },
];

// An array to store prices
let bestPrices = [];
  
function myFunction() {
  allInstruments.forEach(function(instrument) {

    let price = instrument.price;
    let type = instrument.type;
    let description = instrument.description;
    let picture = instrument.picture;

    // HTML
    let html = `<div instrumentType='${type}'class="box instrument" price="${price}">
        <img class="instrument-image" src="${picture}" alt="${picture}">
       <h6 class="price">${price}</h6>
        <p class="instrument-description">${description}</p>
    </div>`;

    // Insert the html to the end of the <div>
    instrumentsContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

    // Store a price to the array
    bestPrices.push(price);
  });
}

// Execute myFunction();
myFunction();

// Check bestPrices
console.log(bestPrices);
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

Personally, I don't think it's necessary to store prices in an array. If you want to get the lowest price, you can do like this:

```js
const allInstruments = [{
    price: 100,
    type: 'something',
    description: 'lorem ipsum',
    picture: './image1.jpg'
  },
  {
    price: 200,
    type: 'something2',
    description: 'lorem ipsum2',
    picture: './image2.jpg'
  },
];

let bestPrice = Math.min(...allInstruments.map(e => e.price));

console.log(bestPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the value of `bestPrice` and `injectInstrument` is change every loop. try to store your value in string array and iterate debug.log through loops.